# Is there an iPad office suite that syncs with Google Docs? 

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, google-docs

The app should support **offline editing** of documents, spreadsheets and sync them back to Google Docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "office kit"?

Comment: as of today, google has its own suite of office apps

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [www.docs.google.com](http://www.docs.google.com) and upgrade your account to a Google Drive account (I believe you can also do this from [www.drive.google.com](http://www.drive.google.com)). Google has an iOS app for their Drive service (just search the app store for “google drive”. You get 5gb of free space for uploaded stuff, and docs created in google docs/drive do not count towards the 5gb. The iOS app has an offline storage option for files, as well as support for folders and starring and sharing

Comment: Also of note, Google has a syncing client for desktop as well.